# How can I make my terminal prompt extend the width of the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, command-prompt, terminal-emulator, ps1

I noticed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2wo0g5fH7c), that the terminal prompt extends the entire width of the terminal before breaking down to a new line.  How can I set my `PS1` variable to fill the remaining terminal space with some character, like the way this user did?

The issue is, I don't know how to update the `PS1` variable per command.  It seems to me, that the string value for `PS1` is only read in once just as the `.bashrc` file is only read in once.  Do I have to write some kind of hook after each command or something?

I should also point out, that the `PS1` variable will be evaluated to a different length based on the escape characters that make up it.  For example, `\w` print the path.

I know I can get the terminal width using `$(COLUMNS)`, and the width of the current `PS1` variable with `${#PS1}`, do the math, and print the right amount of buffer characters, but how do I get it to update everytime.  Is there a preferred way?

Answer (score 7):

Let's suppose you want your prompt to look something like this:

```
left text----------------------------------------------------------right text
prompt$
```

This is pretty straight-forward provided that `right text` has a known size. (For example, it might be the current date and time.) What we do is to print the right number of dashes (or, for utf-8 terminals, the prettier `\u2500`), followed by `right text`, then a carriage return (`\r`, *not* a newline) and the left text, which will overwrite the dashes. The only tricky bit is "the right number of dashes", but we can use `$(tput cols)` to see how wide the terminal is, and fortunately `bash` will command-expand `PS1`. So, for example:

```
PS1='\[$(printf "%*s" $(($(tput cols)-20)) "" | sed "s/ /-/g") \d \t\r\u@\h:\w \]\n\$ '
```

Here, `$(($(tput cols)-20))` is the width of the terminal minus 20, which is based on `\d \t` being exactly 20 characters wide (including the initial space).

`PS1` does not understand utf-8 escapes (`\uxxxx`), and inserting the appropriate substitution into the `sed` command involves an annoying embedded quote issue, although it's possible. However, `printf` does understand utf-8 escapes, so it is easier to produce the sequence of dashes in a different way:

```
PS1='\[$(printf "\\u2500%.0s" $(seq 21 $(tput cols))) \d \t\r\u@\h:\w \]\n\$ '
```

Yet another way to do this involves turning off the terminal's autowrap, which is possible if you are using `xterm` or a terminal emulator which implements the same control codes (or the linux console itself). To disable autowrap, output the sequence <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>. To turn it back on, use <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>. With autowrap disabled, once output reaches the end of a line, the last character will just get overwritten with the next character instead of starting a new line. With this technique, it's not really necessary to compute the exact length of the dash sequence; we just need a string of dashes which is longer than any console will be wide, say the following:

```
DASHES="$(printf '\u2500%0.s' {1..1000})"
PS1='\[\e[?7l\u@\h:\w $DASHES \e[19D \d \t\e[?7h\]\n\$ '
```

Here, `\e[19D` is the terminal-emulator code for "move cursor backwards 19 characters". I could have used `$(tput cub 19)` instead. (There might be a `tput` parameter for turning autowrap on and off, but I don't know what it would be.)

The example in the video also involves inserting a right-aligned string in the actual command line. I don't know any clean way of doing this with `bash`; the console in the video is almost certainly using `zsh` with the `RPROMPT` feature. Of course, you can output right-aligned prompts in `bash`, using the same technique as above, but `readline` won't know anything about them, so as soon as you do something to edit the line, the right prompt will vanish.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to reset the value of `PS1` before each command.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
set_prompt () {
    PS1=...
}
```

Although some system script (or you yourself) may already use `PROMPT_COMMAND` for something, in which case you can simply add to it.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND; set_prompt"
```